# Google sheets automatically adding extra rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering if there is some type of code that can be used when dealing with the appendRow function in google apps scripts.

When I was archiving some old data (cutting and pasting from sheet 1 to sheet 2), apps script got kind of buggy. Now whenever a user submits a form entry, rather than going from row 1000 to 1001 (for example), it will start at row 50500. It doesn't matter if I delete rows 1000 to 50500, it will just restart number at 50500 again.

Do you know if this is an issue with apps script, or if this can be modified somewhere in google sheets directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to improper usage of `=ARRAYFORMULA()`: Like operations between unbound/bound ranges of different lengths: like `A:A` and `A2:A` inside the formula. Remove the formula and the issue will be resolved.

- [Related Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/)

Comment: Is there a way I can still have my formulas carry over without using arrayformula and without using google apps scripts?

Comment: @Anuj Depends on the formula and the script used. Ask a new question with the formula and the script. See [mre] and [ask]