# ArrayFormula is affecting getLastRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4:B="","",(B4:B-A4:A)))` in my spreadsheet. 
And also, I have the `getLastRow()` in the appscript. Apparently the `ArrayFormula` is affecting the `getLastRow()`. Is there a possible workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayFormula is breaking the getLastRow() funtion. Possible workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883862/arrayformula-is-breaking-the-getlastrow-funtion-possible-workarounds)

Comment: @TheMaster somehow it gives me an Idea, but I don't know how to create the proper formula with INDEX/COUNT in it. Can you provide a sample formula?

Comment: Show what you've tried or just use `arrayconstrain()`with `counta()`

Comment: Not yet, I'm not really good at coding or formula.

Comment: @TheMaster answered this question with your suggestion but instead of `counta()` used max row with data to avoid a glitch if we have spaces in the data.

Answer (score 1):

**ArrayFormula is affecting getLastRow**
Yes, that is a feature, it is supposed to change the LastRow because you are outputting an Array all the way to the bottom of the spreadsheet.

Simple fix:

```
=arrayformula(array_constrain(IF(B4:B="","",(B4:B-A4:A)),max(IF(B4:B="",0,row(B4:B)))-row()+1,1))
```

What you were originally doing: *Outputting an Array with mostly blank spaces all the way to the bottom of the spreadsheet*

What this new formula is doing: *Outputting only the data you want by restricting the size of the Array to the last row containing data.*