# How To Loop Google Sheet Formula In App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to set a formula in Google Sheet from Google App Script.

Here's the illustration of the Spreadsheet:
[image]

I also tried to make the code but I don't know how to loop it so for every values added to cell range 'A3:F' will automatically SUM it to the Total column (column G). Could you show me how to loop it? Your response will be appreciated :)

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var cell = s.getRange("G3");
  cell.setFormula("=SUM((A3/100)*D3)+((B3/100)*E3)+((C3/100)*F3)");
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the updated code that works for me:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  const cell = s.getRange(3, 7, s.getLastRow());
  cell.setFormula("=SUM((A3/100)*D3)+((B3/100)*E3)+((C3/100)*F3)");
  
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883862

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop is not needed. SetFormula will automatically adjust to a new range, as if autofilled:

```
  const cell = s.getRange(`G3:G${s.getLastRow()}`);
  cell.setFormula("=SUM((A3/100)*D3)+((B3/100)*E3)+((C3/100)*F3)");
```

Comment: this code looks simple. But I cannot apply it, there's error " Exception: Range not found (line 6, file "sheet") ". Line 6 is where the getLastRow code is. Do you know what's the issue?

Comment: @Ray Is v8 enabled?

Comment: Yupp Chrome V8 enabled

Comment: The one in my question is the full code for my onEdit function. I tried  'const cell = s.getRange(3, 7, s.getLastRow());'  but it shows 0 on the rest of the blank row in the Total column

Comment: @ray *I tried 'const cell = s.getRange(3, 7, s.getLastRow());' but it shows 0 on the rest of the blank row in the Total column* Is there a formula in all of column G?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a "template" for your formula and replace the necessary params with the row number in a loop. Here's an example that sets the formula from row 3 to row 12

```
var ss              = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s               = ss.getSheetByName( 'Sheet1' );
var firstRowNum     = 3;
var lastRowNum      = 12;
var formulas        = [];
var formulaTemplate = '=SUM((A{rowNum}/100)*D{rowNum})+((B{rowNum}/100)*E{rowNum})+((C{rowNum}/100)*F{rowNum})';

for ( var i = firstRowNum; i <= lastRowNum; i++ ) {
    formulas.push( [ formulaTemplate.replace( /{rowNum}/g, i ) ] );
}

s.getRange( 'G' + firstRowNum + ':G' + lastRowNum ).setFormulas( formulas );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a 'simple' function instead of scripts.

SUMPRODUCT is good but it doesn't loop down. You can use the ARRAYFORMULA, but you'll need to list out each multiplication like A/100*D.

To loop down with ARRAYFORMULA, each column range would be in the format A3:A etc.

Your formula in cell G3 would therefore be:

`=ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A/100*D3:D)+(B3:B/100*E3:E)+(C3:C/100*F3:F))`

NOTE: row numbers need to be the same as where you've inserted the main ARRAYFORMULA (ie. 3 as per the example). If you get it wrong, your sheet can generate a huge number of rows before you know it!!