# How to set value in another column of Google Sheets based on certain value of column in the same sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have this sheets that has a lists of email address. I want to auto populate the Column D base on the value of email in column B.

[image]

What I want to auto populate in column D is the first name of the email Address.

What I want, is to look like this:

[image]

let say I know or I can set the first name of the email lists.

- ken@gmail.com = **Ken**
- ben02@hotmail.com = **Ben**
- kobe.brayant@gmail.com = **Kobe**
- lebronJAMES@gmail.com = **Lebron**

The question is how to auto populate column D or (NAME) base on the value of Email Address.

Note that the data (Column A to C) is auto populated base on the Google Forms.

Comment: Could you elaborate *let say I know or I can set the first name of the email lists.*? If the question is just "How to auto populate?", [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63837444/) should answer your question.

Comment: The data on the sheets came from a Google form... so if the new data is came from (let say ken@gmail.com). I want to auto populate the column D with data "Ken" on it.

Comment: But how is  "Ken"  associated with "ken@gmail.com"? Do you have a list? Have you tried anything to populate it?

Comment: Hmmm. if I can set it on the appscript like.. if you see the value "ken@gmail.com" then the return value will be "Ken"

Comment: Yes you can. Preferably with Object/Map(key-value pairs).

Comment: Cool.. can you point me on some example? or sample code on how to set it?

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for "Codelabs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this arrayformula in cell **D1**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"NAME";proper(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),"^[a-z]+"))})
```

[image: output]

---

As a complete solution in **Google Apps Script** you could do that:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  const emails = sh.getRange("B2:B"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const names = emails.map(str=>str.match('^[a-z]+')[0])
                .map(name=>name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+name.slice(1));
  sh.getRange("D2:D"+sh.getLastRow()).setValues(names.map(nm=>[nm]));
}
```

Assuming the sheet name is **Form Responses 1**.

---

For illustration:

```js
const emails = ['ken@gmail.com','kobe.brayant@gmail.com',
                  'ben02@hotmail.com','lebronJAMES@gmail.com']; 
const names = emails.map(str=>str.match('^[a-z]+')[0])
                .map(name=>name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+name.slice(1));
console.log(names);
```

---

Comment: Is there a way for me to set the NAME value? let say for email (ben02@hotmail) the NAME value will be Benjamin?

Comment: Is this doable in Appscript?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that. You can only do that manually like if(d2="Ben","Benjamin) or something. You can use GAS but this formula will be way faster a more maintanable in the future. @kendy

Comment: what do mean by manually do it by (d2="Ben","Benjamin)? where do I set it?

Comment: @kendy see sample code regarding a Google Apps Script solution. Could you let me know if that worked for you?

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse... where is the part where I set the email (ben02@hotmail) that get the name "Ben" to "Benjamin".

Comment: @kendy replace the google formula in my solution with this and put it again in cell D1: `=ARRAYFORMULA({"NAME";if(proper(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),"^[a-z]+"))="Ben","Benjamin",proper(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),"^[a-z]+")))})`

Comment: I think I'll use this ARRAYFORMULA...last question so I can still use this formula to set the other name like if I set the email (ken@gmail.com) that get the name "Ken" to "Kendy".  together with "Ben" to "Benjamin"

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA({"NAME";if(proper(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),"^[a-z]+"))="Ben","Benjamin",if(proper(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),"^[a-z]+"))="Ken","Kendy",proper(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),"^[a-z]+"))))})` @kendy