# binding (or freezing) automated rows and manual edited rows in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, data-binding, data-cleaning

I am using google sheets for a qualitative research.

I have some columns, say column C, manipulated with formulas and aggregations on raw data in columns A and B.

Aside column C, I want to have a column D used for manual annotations.

I want to ensure that, if I make a change in any row in A or B, that will reflect to a change in rows in A, I bind rows of C and D.

example:

imagine I have in column A a list of words, some with plural and singular form:

```
A
apple
pears
word
words
```

in column C, I count them:

```
C     count
pears 12
word  5
words 6
apple 1
```

In column D, I annotate them:

```
C     count     D
pears 12        comment about pears
word  5         a comment
words 6         another comment
apple 1        comment about apple
```

Now, I would like to merge rows in column A, by plural (that can be manual editing):

```
A 
words // word is removed
```

so that I would have:

```
C     count
pears 12
words 11   // words is the results of row data : "words" and "word" after data cleaning
apple 1
```

My issue is that I want to ensure that rows of D are binding with C:
if for any reason, I alter the number or order of rows in C, rows in D should shuffle (or be removed, if the "parent" C rows is no more existing).

```
C        D
pears    comment about pears line is still linked to pears
words    another comment
apple    comment about apple line is still linked to apple
```

Is that possible?

I am looking at documentation and FREEZE, but that's completely another thing.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837444/

Comment: Add the annotations in another sheet (A: pears/pear, B: comment about pears) and do a [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) in Column D of the main sheet

Comment: @idfurw if there are not repeated items, is a good idea! Thank you