# How do I combine a first and last name google form response into a new full name column?

Tags: google-apps-script

On google sheets, I have google form response sheet: A column for first name and a column for last name. I've used the =ARRAYFORMULA(A5& " "&B5) command to combine the first and last name into a new column C with full names. When I type in a new first and last name, it automatically adds the full name to the new column. But when a new first and last name is added through the google form, it doesn't automatically add it until I drag down in the full name column. How do I fix this so when the google form is submitted it will add the full name automatically without having to drag it down?

| First Name | Last Name | Full Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob (Typed in) | Smith (Typed in) | Bob Smith |
| Mike (Google Form Response) | McDonald (Google Form Response) | ____________ |

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63837444/

Answer (score 0):

Using the onFormSubmit trigger:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) { 
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,3).setValue(`${e.values[1]} ${e.values[2]}`)
}
```

or whatever their indexes in the values array is

- [onFormSubmit(e) Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Another easy option without using apps script, is to automatically concatenate the form data in the column with an array formula. As per your example-table, you could add in cell C1 the following formula

`={"Full Name";ArrayFormula(A2:A&" "&B2:B)}`

this uses an Array literal to set the column header, followed by the concatenated data from de referenced columns.