# How to remove empty arrays from multidimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with removing empty arrays/objects from a multidimensional array for my search app in google sheets. I am using `getLastRow` so I thought I will avoid this problem but unfortunately it is not.

My array looks like this:

```
[[1.39080000912E11, RSSMA004025, ﾎﾞﾀﾝｷｬｯﾌﾟ M4X25, 4.0, 4.2, , , ], [1.39080000912E11, RWJAA058068, FTB-268, 1.0, 486.0, 486.0, , ], [, , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , ]]
```

And I am looking for something that will delete empty arrays from the end of the array so it should be like this:

```
[[1.39080000912E11, RSSMA004025, ﾎﾞﾀﾝｷｬｯﾌﾟ M4X25, 4.0, 4.2, , , ], [1.39080000912E11, RWJAA058068, FTB-268, 1.0, 486.0, 486.0, , ]]
```

It is just a part of the whole array but I hope you will understand what I am looking for.

My code so far:

```
function getDataForSearch(){
    
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("WP");
  
  var test1 = ws.getRange(4, 6, ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();

const arrFiltered = test1.filter(function(x){
  return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));
});

 Logger.log(arrFiltered);

}
```

Comment: in your function `const arrFiltered = test1.filter(function(x){
  return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));
});`, x is an array. not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use filter() and some()

```js
var arr = [[1.39080000912E11, 'RSSMA004025', 'ﾎﾞﾀﾝｷｬｯﾌﾟ M4X25', 4.0, 4.2, , , ], [1.39080000912E11, 'RWJAA058068', 'FTB-268', 1.0, 486.0, 486.0, , ], [, , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , ]];

// Will fail for falsly values, but works in this case
var updated1 = arr.filter(function (a) {
  return a.some(Boolean);
});

// var updated1 = arr.filter(a => a.some(Boolean));
console.log(updated1);

// check for undefined
var updated2 = arr.filter(function (a) {
  return a.some(function (val) {
    return val !== undefined;
  });;
});

// var updated2 = arr.filter(a => a.some(val => val !== undefined));
console.log(updated2);

//If it can be any of the values
var empty = [undefined, null, ''];
var updated3 = arr.filter(function (a) {
  return a.some(function (val) {
    return !empty.includes(val);
  });
});

// var updated3 = arr.filter(a => a.some(val => !empty.includes(val)));
console.log(updated3);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! the method using `Boolean` is working perfect, for me.
I have no idea why the `undefined` is not working at all.... Do you think that it is because in some empty elements there are formulas without any output?

Answer (score 2):

Your function should look like

```js
function getDataForSearch() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("WP");

  var test1 = ws.getRange(4, 6, ws.getLastRow(), 8).getValues();

  const arrFiltered = test1.filter(function (x) { /* here, x is an array, not an object */
    return !(x.every(element => element === (undefined || null || '')))
  });

  Logger.log(arrFiltered);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am using getLastRow so I thought I will avoid this problem but unfortunately it is not.

[`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) syntax is

```
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
```

The script is using

```
ws.getRange(4, 6, ws.getLastRow(), 8).getValues();
```

The third parameter is `numRows`- the number of rows. If the last row is 10, You're getting the range from row 4 to row 14(4+10). To end at row 10, number of rows should be 7. The correct range  should be therefore be

```
ws.getRange(1 + 3, 6, ws.getLastRow() - 3, 8).getValues();
```

Another  possibility for such empty rows  would be the  traditional use of array formulas. See [ArrayFormula is breaking the getLastRow() funtion. Possible workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883862/)

Comment: yes I was thinking about it but the whole array had like 10 non empty elements and 100 empty so I guess it was not the problem

Comment: @Timonek Edited my answer to provide another possibility.

Comment: so the formulas that are in the cells are messing up the `getLastRow()`.... I will remember that for next time

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this perhaps. You want to only remove the arrays where all of the array elements are undefined.

```
var funnyArrays = [['a', 'b', 'c'],  [,,,], ['d','e','f'], [,,,]];

var fullArrays = funnyArrays.filter(a => !a.every(ax=> a == undefined));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can join the elements in the array and then check their length for filtering

```js
let test1 = [[1.39080000912E11, 'RSSMA004025', 'uiuiu M4X25', 4.0, 4.2, , , ],[1.39080000912E11, 'RWJAA058068;', 'FTB - 268', 1.0, 486.0, 486.0, , ],[, , , , , , , ],[, , , , , , , ]]


const arrFiltered = test1.filter(function(x) {
  return (x.join('').length !== 0);
});

console.log('new array',arrFiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try that.

```js
const notEmptyArrayOrObject = (arr)=> {

  if(typeof arr !== 'object'){ return true }

  if(!Array.isArray(arr){
     arr = Object.values(arr)
  }

  return arr.filter(item=>item === undefined).length !== arr.length
}

const filterEmptyFromArray = (array)=>array.filter(notEmptyArrayOrObject)
```