# Google Apps Script range is longer than expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cannot understand how this is happening. As you see I logged out the values of the range and it should be only 10 rows with the cells containing data (from row 1300 to 1310. But, when I log out the newItems, the range goes down to the last row of the sheet. Could you please enlighten me what am I missing?

Thank you.

```
let newItems = sPayoutPayments.getRange(sMasterPayoutLogLR+1,1,sPayoutPaymentsLR,sPayoutPaymentsLC).getValues()

  Logger.log(sMasterPayoutLogLR+1 +"," + "1," + sPayoutPaymentsLR +","+ sPayoutPaymentsLC)
  Logger.log(newItems)
```

> 7:32:01 AM    Info    1300,1,1310,10
>
> 7:32:01 AM    Info    Logging output too large. Truncating output. [[Mon Mar
> 13 14:03:58 GMT-04:00 2023, Szalai-Szabó Hanna, 10500.0, Bankkártya,
> Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás A&L, 1.0, 0.0,
> 0.0], [Mon Mar 13 15:16:53 GMT-04:00 2023, Gregor Luca, 10500.0, Bankkártya, Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás A&L,
> 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [Mon Mar 13 15:16:59 GMT-04:00 2023, Siklódi Enikő, 10500.0, Bankkártya, Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás A&L, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [Mon Mar 13 15:18:41 GMT-04:00 2023,
> Maróthi Csaba, 14000.0, Készpénz, Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00
> 2023, FS Tanítás A&L, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0], [Mon Mar 13 16:40:14 GMT-04:00
> 2023, Wéber Dóra, 10500.0, Készpénz, Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00
> GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás A&L, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [Mon Mar 13 16:41:52
> GMT-04:00 2023, Gyuranecz Fanni, 10500.0, Bankkártya, Óra, Tue Feb 28
> 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás A&L, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0], [Tue Mar 14
> 14:22:25 GMT-04:00 2023, Endreffy Kornélia, 3500.0, Bankkártya, Óra,
> Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás C&B, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
> [Tue Mar 14 15:38:16 GMT-04:00 2023, Teőke Ágoston, 3500.0, Készpénz,
> Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás C&B, 1.0, 0.0,
> 1.0], [Thu Mar 16 11:14:31 GMT-04:00 2023, Ressely Fanni, 10500.0, Készpénz, Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás A&L,
> 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [Thu Mar 16 14:02:43 GMT-04:00 2023, Pusztai Dorina, 7000.0, Bankkártya, Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023, FS Tanítás A&L, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [Thu Mar 16 15:04:11 GMT-04:00 2023, Nagy
> Henrietta, 3500.0, Készpénz, Óra, Tue Feb 28 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2023,
> FS Tanítás A&L, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , ,
> , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ],
> [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, ,
> , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , ,
> , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , ,
> , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , ,
> , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ],
> [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , ,

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns

Comment: @NEWAZA https://stackoverflow.com/a/65785610/ explains it and therefore it is closed as duplicate.