Update data based on ID or append new row if ID not on list
I have a Google Sheet with report data that needs validaiton. I have created a User Form (Validation_1 tab) to pull the report data into for ease of reading. On the User Form the data is validated against the source system to ensure correct values are pulled per preset specifications. As the data is validated, dropdowns in column E are used to enter comments such as 'Agree, Disagree, etc'. Each record/case on the report has a unique ID that is placed in cell C2 of the User Form.
I managed to write script to Save column E info to a 'Data' tab based on finding the unique ID in column 'A' of the Data tab. For this to work I have to pre-load the IDs into the 'Data' tab.
I would like to be able to update the Data tab if changes are made to a record or append data to a new row if the ID does not exist on the 'Data' tab.
My current code has const defined to include the non-contigous cells in column E.
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  
      const updatesourceRangeE = ["C5","E6","E7","E9","E11","E13"]
  
      const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("Validation_1")
      const idCell = formWS.getRange("c2")
      const id = idCell.getValue()

    function saveData(){
       const idFound = dataWS.getRange("A:A").createTextFinder(id).matchEntireCell(true).findNext() 
       const idRow = idFound.getRow() 
    
       const colEdata = updatesourchRangeE.map(f => 
    formWS.getRange(f).getValue())
      colEdata.unshift(id)
      dataWS.getRange(idRow,1,1,colEdata.length).setValues([colEdata])
    }

I've tried to modify different codes found on this site and others but I don't have a good enough understanding to intergrate them into my current code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated
EDIT: further explanation...
Validation tab (source sheet) example
 |---|A-Empty col|B-Report headers|C-Report Info|D-Empty Col|E-User Input|
 |:-:|:----------|:--------------:|:-----------:|:---------:|:----------:|
 |1  |           |                |             |           |            |
 |2  |           | Unique ID:     |12345        |           |            |
 |3  |           |                |             |           |            |
 |4  |           | Demographics   |Report data  |           | Comment    |
 |5  |           | Name:          |John Doe     |           | Agree      |
 |6  |           | Date of Bith:  |9/15/64      |           | Disagree incorrect year|
 |7  |           | Insurance ID:  | R8384958    |           | Agree      |
 |8  |           |                |             |           |            |
 |9  |           | Arrival date:  | 8/1/24      |           | Agree      |
 |10 |           |                |             |           |            |
 |11 |           | Procedure date:| 8/3/24      |           | UTD - record not available|
 |12 |           |                |             |           |            |
 |13 |           | Depart date:   | 8/5/24      |           | Agree      |

Data tab (destination sheet) example
 |---|   A      |B       |C       |D       |E        |F      |G      |
 |:-:|:--------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:-------:|:-----:|:-----:|
 |1  |Unique ID |  Name  |  DOB   |Insur ID|Arrival  |Proc   |Depart |
 |2  |  12345   |John Doe| Agree  |Disagree incorrect year|Agree|Agree|UTD-record not available|Agree|
 |3  |  67890   |Nancy   |Agree   |Agree      |Agree    |Agree |Agree|
 |4  |  13579   |        |        |           |         |      |     |
 |5  |  24680   |        |        |           |         |      |     |
 |6  |          |        |        |           |         |      |     |
 |7  |          |        |        |           |         |      |     |

Current state: the above coding will write to the destination page IF the unique ID is already in column A of the destination tab. Which is part of what I want.
What I'm looking to add to the code is:
The ability to add a new Unique ID (ABCDE) to the Source sheet cell C2 that is not already listed on the destination sheet, complete the form and 'save'. The action would search for the new ID (ABCDE) on the destination sheet (Data) and when it is not found it would then append the information to the next available row. In this example it would populate row 6, columns A-G.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm trying to figure out how to ... once data is entered into user form to check the destination sheet for the unique ID and if found update the row of data associated with that unique ID OR if the ID is not on the destination form, add the data to the next available row.

It's unclear how many rows in "Data" contain the unique ID and/or how the layout of a row in "Data" relates to the dropdown values in the non-contigous cells in column E. Would you please edit the question to include sample data for both "Data" and "Validation 1" as well as an example of the expected outcome(s).

There's a comment for the name "Agree", should there be an extra column to the right of "Name" for this comment?

You have two sheets "Validation_1" and "Data".

Validation_1 - created by a report and, by using several Data Validation cell, gives users the ability to express comments on the report data
Data - a sheet where validated information is updated.

A key feature is a Unique ID which is included in the "Validation" sheet as well as the "Data" sheet
When a user completes validation of a report, you want the data to be updated to the corresponding UniqueID on "Data". If the UniqueID can't be found on "Data", you want to add a new row on "Data" containing all the information from the "Validation" sheet.
Consider this answer:

Users initiate the updateData function at their option via a Custom menu.
The script includes controls to test for incomplete information. If information is incomplete, processing is stopped and a warning can be given/message generated.

Tested fields: Unique ID, Name, 6 x Comments
An Alert is given as an example for a missing Unique ID.
The OP can decide what actions(s) are take place when an incomplete test fails.


The only information extracted from "Data" is Column A containing the Unique ID.

The Unique ID is tested against "Data" using indexOf
when the UniqueID can't be found" (indexOf returns -1), a new record is appended to the "Data" sheet
when the Unique ID is found, the row number is calculated and only the comments are updated.




/**
 * The event handler triggered when opening the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onOpen event.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Update Data sheet', 'updateData')
    .addToUi();
}

function updateData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var valSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Validation_1")
  
  // get UniqueID and name
  var uId = valSheet.getRange("C2").getValue()
  Logger.log("DBUG: The Report unique ID = "+uId)
  if (uId.length <1){
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Unique ID is blank")
    // script stopped
    // do something to warn user, for example
    /*
      // Display a prompt box to user 
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert('Processing error: Unique ID is Blank', 'Processing halted', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    */
    return
  }
 
  // get the name
  var name = valSheet.getRange("C5").getValue()
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the Report name = "+name)
  if (name.length <1){
    Logger.log("DEBUGL The name is blank")
    // script stopped
    // do something to warn user
    return
  }
  
  // get the Comments
  var comments = valSheet.getRange("E5:E13").getValues()
  // delete blanks
  // How to remove empty arrays from multidimensional array in JavaScript?
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/65784769/1330560
  // @LogiStack
  var filteredComments = comments.filter(function (x) { 
    return !(x.every(element => element === (undefined || null || '')))
  })
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the number of Comments = "+filteredComments.length)
  if(filteredComments.length != 6){
    Logger.log("Insufficient comments")
    // script stopped
    // do something to warn user
    return
  }
  // flatten the comments to 1D array
  filteredComments = filteredComments.flat()
  Logger.log(filteredComments) // DEBUG

  // find a match for the Unique ID on Data
  // get the IDs
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  // get the number of rows in Column A
  var dataAVals = dataSheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues()
  var dataALast = dataAVals.filter(String).length
  var dataIDList = dataSheet.getRange(2,1,dataALast,1).getValues().flat()
  Logger.log(dataIDList) // DEBUG
  // find the UniqueId in the data List
  var idIndex = dataIDList.indexOf(uId)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the id index = "+idIndex)
  if (idIndex == -1){
    // if -1, then UID not founbd, so create new row
    var tempArray1 = new Array
    tempArray1.push(uId,name)
    var tempArray2 = tempArray1.concat(filteredComments);
    Logger.log(tempArray2) // DEBUG
    // append the new row
    dataSheet.appendRow(tempArray2);
    return
  }
  // update an existing row
  var dataUpdateRange = dataSheet.getRange((+idIndex+2),3,1,6)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range to update =  "+dataUpdateRange.getA1Notation())
  dataUpdateRange.setValues([filteredComments])
}


Sample - Validation - existing ID


Sample - Validation - new ID


Sample - Data (before)


Sample - Data (after update-existing ID)


Sample - Data (after update - new ID)


Thank you for your input. I am unable to test just now as other fires need to be extinquished. I will let you know as soon as I can.
