# My coding puts the information in the last rows in the sheet, not the last available row

Tags: google-apps-script

so I have added coding to copy information from one sheet to another, but it puts it in at line 2000 +, not in the next available line. How can I change it? It needs to go into the next available line, not at the bottom. I have used .getLastRow() how can I go further?

Comment: I would suggest you post your code.  Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: If there are formulas in adjacent columns, that may be the reason... Cooper's answer below should help, but try to post a practical example of your issue, so that it gets easier for folks to help.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883862/arrayformula-is-breaking-the-getlastrow-funtion-possible-workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column

Answer (score 1):

#### Last Available Empty Line or first empty line above the end

```
function lastavailableline() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const shsr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(shsr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let mts = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r.every(e => e == "")) {
      mts.push(i + shsr);
    }
  })
  Logger.log(mts.reverse()[0]);
}
```

It sounded to me that this is what the op was asking.