# Converting horizontal search in Match to arrayformula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

I've a table which has many columns(below is just sample data, in original I've many of those two repeated columns), table look like this :-

[image]

I am using this formula to look for Match and get column left to it for Account Name

```
=INDEX(A3:D3,1,MATCH(G3,A3:E3,0)-1)
```

I need to drag this, because it's not an arrayformula
[image]

Can we make it an arrayformula, or is there any other way to do it, other than this using arrayformula?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on Excel or google-sheet? Share a sample workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF` a range contains a value, chose the range to the left of it  and join the resulting array.

#### Minimal reproducible example:

```
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E=B2:D,A2:C,)),LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",1,r)))
```

| (A1)Account | Position | Account | Position | Search | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Apple | a | Apple2 | Apple | a |
| a | Cherry | a | Cherry2 | Cherry2 | a |
| b | Apple | b | Apple2 | Apple | b |
| c | Apple | c | Orange | Orange | c |

If you just want the first match, use `INDEX/MATCH`:

```
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:LR(E:E)=B2:LR(D:D),A2:LR(C:C),)),LAMBDA(r,LR(r)))
```

where `LR` is a named function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/)

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula-

```
=BYROW(G2:G9,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(FILTER(A2:A9,D2:D9=x,ROW(D2:D9)>=ROW(x)),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: In your language `=BYROW(G2:G9,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(FILTER(A2:A9,D2:D9=x,ZEILE(D2:D9)>=ZEILE(x)),1)))`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer what if I have more column, in my original sheet i've 80+ of those repeated column, , I added two more Account Name in sheet, and this formula breaks I think, thank you once again

Comment: Its the Error Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula.  driving me crazy See [this erorr](https://i.imgur.com/dLLsAUg.png) Maybe try `IF(ROW(range)<=ROW(range),`

Comment: Ya, I've been banging my head too, formula is simple when you're ready to drag it down, but with Array, i can't think of any possible solution

Comment: No i ment the `LAMBDA` formula throws limitation error, if you have limited rows your ok, if you have a lot of rows its not a good solution, hopefully @Harun24hr will update the anser with option 2,  [see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866211/converting-horizontal-search-in-match-to-arrayformula#comment130429387_73866479)

Comment: I am new to Lambda Function :P