# Horizontal Lookup using Index Match on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup, index-match

For the following image from Google Sheets, I want to fill out column L with the value found in column A "PPID" based on values in column J "ID" and referencing the range columns B-I. For example, the value "123" should be filled out in column L for the IDs in column J that are 981296581, 682975586, etc. I tried using Index-Match formula, such as =INDEX($A$3, MATCH(J3,B3, 0)), but it only worked for the first row of data and showed an error for the remaining rows

Here is the screenshot of my Google Sheets, as well as the tables below it if you need to copy it into your Google Sheets:

[image]

**SHEET 1**

| PPID | ID | ID | ID | ID | ID | ID | ID | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 981296581 | 682975586 | 6144233 | 6140531 | 6047231 | 4540543 | 134 | 34 |
| 456 | 815220681 | 1532839 | 1141531 |  |  |  |  |  |

**SHEET 2**

| ID | INTENDED RESULT | COLUMN TO FILL OUT (with formula) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 981296581 | 123 |  |
| 682975586 | 123 |  |
| 6144233 | 123 |  |
| 6140531 | 123 |  |
| 6047231 | 123 |  |
| 4540543 | 123 |  |
| 134 | 123 |  |
| 34 | 123 |  |
| 815220681 | 456 |  |
| 1532839 | 456 |  |
| 1141531 | 456 |  |

Thanks!

Comment: Just added the sample in table format

Comment: [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. player0's solution below is the one I tried and it worked for me. I upvoted that one :)

Answer (score 3):

The format isn't really conducive for a lookup. We can `FLATTEN` the key range and "repeat and flatten" the value range(with `IF`) to make it conducive for any lookup.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  XLOOKUP(
    K2:K12,
    FLATTEN(B2:I3),
    FLATTEN(IF(COLUMN(B2:I3),A2:A3,))
  )
)
```

| ID(K1) | INTENDED RESULT | COLUMN TO FILL OUT (with formula) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 981296581 | 123 | 123 |
| 682975586 | 123 | 123 |
| 6144233 | 123 | 123 |
| 6140531 | 123 | 123 |
| 6047231 | 123 | 123 |
| 4540543 | 123 | 123 |
| 134 | 123 | 123 |
| 34 | 123 | 123 |
| 815220681 | 456 | 456 |
| 1532839 | 456 | 456 |
| 1141531 | 456 | 456 |

Comment: To complete the formula, adding an `IFERROR` would take care of possible empty cells.

Comment: @marikamitsos I don't do that, unless necessary for chaining formula logic. If there are errors, I want them to show :)

Comment: Fair enough.  I just think that errors produced by empty cells are not a necessity and could in general be *"hidden"*.

Comment: @marikamitsos I don't think empty cells should even be referenced. I'm [not a fan of open ended ranges either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/), where it seems like nothing is in the cells, but something is.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of open ranges. Simply referring to a situation where say cell `F2` was empty. My original thought was that column `J` would be created using `=FLATTEN(B2:H3)`. In this case if `F2` would be empty, one would not end up with a *"solid"* column as presented in the example. Errors would interrupt the results.

Comment: @marikamitsos Fair enough. But, IMO, `N/A` is a better status than a empty cell, as it clearly shows that it is not available rather than hiding any other error.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3:J, IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B3:I="",,B3:I&"×"&A3:A)), "×")), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3="",,
 BYROW(B3:I3, LAMBDA(l, IF(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(REGEXMATCH(J3&"",l&"")), "Select Col1 where Col1 = TRUE"),1,1)<>TRUE,,A3)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Osm, the value 123 (not 456) should be filled out in cell L4. Value 123 should be filled out for cells L3-L10 and 456 for cells L11-L13