# Any easy way to simplify a repetitive formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dry

Do you have any suggestions on how to reduce the effort on typing the formula below

```
={"Header";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(dosomething(),"-")),COUNTA(A2:A),1)}
```

I make calculations everyday on several files, and I have to do this for most of the columns to auto-calculate data. I type it several times.

Is there any way to reduce the effort?

Comment: Excel or Google sheets? `dosomething()`?

Comment: @Osm is just an example of a formula

Comment: You want to return the first result of any formula and a header on top?

Comment: Please edit your question to assign the proper tags, your formula seems to be from Google Spreadsheet. `ARRAYFORMULA` is not an excel function.

Comment: You can make a named function `=ArrayFormula({"Header";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(dosomething,"-")),COUNTA(range),1)})` but without knowing what `dosomething()`? is, its pointless.

Comment: I think you are falling into XY problem, see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce it by creating a [named function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534).

Create a function like:

`CUSTOMCUT`:

**Arguments**: `arr`
**Description**: The array to cut up to the count of `Sheet1!A2:A`
**Formula definition**: `={"Header";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(arr,"-")),COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A),1)}`

Then you can use:

```
=CUSTOMCUT(dosomething())
```

#### Related:

[Avoiding  traditional usage of arrayformula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/)

Comment: definitely that's useful, I didn't know about it...next time I'll read the entire help center articles