# In Google Sheets, how can I find the value in a column of a row when you know the lookup column name and result column name?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a `Sheet1` with data like this:

| one | two | three | four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |
| e | f | g | h |
| i | j | k | l |
| m | n | o | p |

I have `Sheet2` with data like this:

| alpha | value |
| --- | --- |
| c |  |
| k |  |
| g |  |
| c |  |

For each row in `Sheet2`, I want to look up `Sheet2`.`alpha` in `Sheet1`.`three` and return the value of `Sheet1`.`one`. I want to do this by putting an array formula in `B2`.

So, the expected result is:

| alpha | value |
| --- | --- |
| c | a |
| k | i |
| g | e |
| c | a |

I can use the new Google Sheet formulas they just released -- except named ranges. I feel like there is some clever trick using them, but I can't come up with it.

Comment: Please make a representative sample showing different results. Preferably as a new question. As this question already has a answer based on your old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BYROW()` and `XLOOKUP()` are your friend in this case.

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!A2:A,"Not Found")))
```

[image]

Comment: What is `A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))`? I've never seen that kind of structure.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/

Comment: I realized I forgot to include something in my question. I edited it. You hardcoded `Sheet1!C2:C` but I need to be able to look up columns by column name.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Then try index/match instead xlookup `=BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(Sheet1!C:D,MATCH(x,Sheet1!C:C,0),MATCH("three",Sheet1!C1:D1,0))))`.