# Assign VLookup to many rows of one Column under Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Having a problem with VLOOKUP under Google Sheets.

I have this basic command that I am trying to assign to each row of a column (there are 200 rows):

```
=Vlookup(D1,KDCAssets!A1:F500,5,false)
```

I want to assign this to a column. When doing so, **I am expecting** something like this:

```
Row 1    =Vlookup(D1,KDCAssets!A1:F500,5,false)
Row 2    =Vlookup(D2,KDCAssets!A1:F500,5,false)
Row 3    =Vlookup(D3,KDCAssets!A1:F500,5,false)
Row 4    =Vlookup(D4,KDCAssets!A1:F500,5,false)
```

The **D** value *increases* but **A** and **F** values *remain the same* **( i.e. A1 and F500 )**. But what I am getting is something like:

```
Row 1    =Vlookup(D1,KDCAssets!A1:F500,5,false) 
Row 2    =Vlookup(D2,KDCAssets!A2:F501,5,false) <- increases by 1
Row 3    =Vlookup(D3,KDCAssets!A3:F502,5,false) <- increases by 1
Row 4    =Vlookup(D4,KDCAssets!A4:F503,5,false) <- increases by 1
```

The range values starting with **A1** and **F500**  *increases* with each successive row. But, **for the lookup**, I need to *be the same for each row*. How can I get this to act properly?

TIA

Comment: `=Vlookup(D1,KDCAssets!A$1:F$500,5,false)`. Reference: [Why use dollar sign ($) in Excel formulas - absolute and relative cell references](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/relative-absolute-reference-excel/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I wound up using: =IF(ISBLANK(D7), "", Vlookup(D7,KDCAssets!A:F,5,false) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use new lambda function `BYROW()` to make it dynamic spill array.

```
=BYROW(D1:INDEX(D1:D,COUNTA(D1:D)),LAMBDA(x,Vlookup(x,KDCAssets!A1:F,5,false)))
```

- Here `D1:INDEX(D1:D,COUNTA(D1:D))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **D1** to last non empty cell in column D (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply `Vlookup()` function for each cell of D column.