# Index formula on multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to use this index formula on multiple columns?

```
=index(if(Sheet1!B5:B<>"",,Sheet1!A5:A))
```

[Sample Table][image: 1]

For the table above, what if we want to add Column C? (If column B and C have data on Sheet 1 - remove them, and if 1 is missing in either column(B or C), it will appear.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Just add a another nested `IF` or try  `IFS`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/

Answer (score 0):

The desired results shown in the screenshot suggest that you want the matching data without inserting blank rows in between. To get that, use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(Sheet1!A5:A, isblank(Sheet1!B5:B)`

To add another criterion, and combine the criteria with `OR`, use the `+` operator, like this:

`=filter(Sheet1!A5:A, isblank(Sheet1!B5:B) + isblank(Sheet1!C5:C))`

To get an `AND` condition, simply add criteria as their own parameters, or use the `*` operator. See [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER()` with `MMULT()` may give you desired result.

```
 =FILTER(Sheet1!A4:A,MMULT(INDEX(--(Sheet1!B4:C="x")),{1;1})<2)
```

- Here `MMULT(INDEX(--(Sheet1!B4:C="x")),{1;1})` will create a vertical array having count how many `x` do you have in each row. If you have `x` in both column of each row then `MMULT()` will return result `2`. If you have one `x` then will return `1` and if there is no `x` then `0`. Then we will filter that vertical array having values less than `2`.

[MMULT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292?hl=en#:%7E:text=Calculates%20the%20matrix%20product%20of%20two%20matrices%20specified%20as%20arrays%20or%20ranges.) reference.

[image]