# Shift Time Between Calculation Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, nested-if

I am trying to calculate the salary for employees in Google Sheets.

**Night Shift** -   if shift start time lies between 12 am-6am
**Day Shift**   - if shift start time lies between 6am-11:59pm

I am able to calculate the salary for night shift employee(D7), I dont know to what am I doing wrong, but I cant seem to add more conditions like day shift and if employee present.

my requirement is:

```
if employee present & Night shift then 500  
if employee present & day shift then 400
```

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF((TIMEVALUE(A8)>=TIMEVALUE("4:00:00"))*(TIMEVALUE(B8)< TIMEVALUE("10:00:00")), 250,IF((TIMEVALUE(A8)>=TIMEVALUE("06:00:00"))*
(TIMEVALUE(B8)<=TIMEVALUE("23:59:59")), 225 && IF(REGEXMATCH(C8, "P|p"),  225, 0))))

any help is appreciate. Here is the [link for the Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XutUKvhnA1I74Z9RebnmTAOATarYWCiBWNj12yOPwic/edit#gid=0) I am trying.

Here is the formula I am tryin:

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do `&&` in your cell, but you should use `AND(condition1, condition2)`

Comment: what is difference between `12 am-6am` and `11:59pm-5:59AM`? Only 1 minute? So, when shift starts at `5:00 AM` then what shift it will be?

Comment: oh shoot! I meant to write 12am-6am as night and  6am-11:59pm as day shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(C7:C="Present", IFNA(VLOOKUP(A7:A, 
 {0, 500; "6:00"*1, 400; "12:00"*1, 500}, 2, 1)), ))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for suggesting an answer. I tried the formula, but the shift time does not change in case of the day shift. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XutUKvhnA1I74Z9RebnmTAOATarYWCiBWNj12yOPwic/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Ophelia answer updated. try now

Comment: Thanks again! I have accepted the answer. I just realized that I didn't noticed I have been using AM/PM in my dropdown list of my shift selection and if time is after 12PM the amount is taking as 500(as if its for night shift). What am I missing in this formula? 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XutUKvhnA1I74Z9RebnmTAOATarYWCiBWNj12yOPwic/edit#gid=0

Two things: considering AM/PM in my dropdown & the actual night shift itself is not considering. I know I have been pestering too much. Any help is appreciated and yet let me know where to look for an answer. Thank you so much

Comment: @Ophelia yeah those AM/PM times of yours gets confusing so if you could clarify it ( exact times for shifts and their points) it would be helpful to fix the formula to act exactly as you wish. lets try this: there are 2 shifts Night and Day. Night is from 00:00 to 06:00 and Day is from 06:00 to 12:00 ? is that correct? so from 12:00 to 00:00 midnight is what?

Comment: Each shift is 3 hours. It's part-time voluntary work. 

night shift - any shift starts between 12:00 AM till 6:00 AM. 
e.g: 12AM to 3AM, 4AM - 7AM. - Rs.500
day shift - any shift starts between 6:00 AM till 11:59 PM.  - Rs.400

Comment: @Ophelia is this correct? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPUxL.png

Comment: yes, the above screenshot is correct. Perhaps use this sheet for reference and trying? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XutUKvhnA1I74Z9RebnmTAOATarYWCiBWNj12yOPwic/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Ophelia in that case formula is: `=INDEX(IF(C7:C="Present", IFNA(VLOOKUP(A7:A, 
 {0, 500; "6:00"*1, 400}, 2, 1)), ))`

Comment: I hesitated to ask this yet did it for a quicker turnaround. I thank you in advance for this. 

I wanted to one more scenario to the formula. I have introduced a new column D. If IDs used less than or equal to 40, then half the pay. i.e, day shift scenario: >40 Ids = 500, <=40 ids = 250 for day.  Night shift scenario: >40 Ids = 400, <=40 ids = 200 for day. I tried to achieve this and failed in D4. Can you please guide me? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AUz-2cdoBiZGFoO1KhJUtgUK-MCBLJun3f3S3P6DlOg/edit#gid=1844257360

Comment: @Ophelia sheet is private

Comment: I am sorry, I have made it public! 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AUz-2cdoBiZGFoO1KhJUtgUK-MCBLJun3f3S3P6DlOg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ophelia try like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReK4m.png

Answer (score 1):

Try `XLOOKUP()` function-

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(A7:A9,{TIME(0,0,0);TIME(6,0,0)},{500;400},,-1))
```

For dynamic spill array use `BYROW()` function.

```
=BYROW(A7:INDEX(A7:A,COUNTA(A7:A)),LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,{TIME(0,0,0);TIME(6,0,0)},{500;400},,-1)))
```

- Here `A7:INDEX(A7:A,COUNTA(A7:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A7** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply ***XLOOKUP()*** function for each cell of ***A column***.
- `XLOOKUP()` with ***match_mode*** `-1` indicate to lookup shift time or next lower value. Means, when you looking for shift `5:00 AM`, it will match with `0` means `12:00 AM` and return `500`. Otherwise will match to `6:00 AM` and return `400` as day shift starts from `6:00 AM`.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your time @Harun24hr, but this does not work. The present/absent condition nor the shift start time logic is picked up by the formula.