# Create a function that returns really nothing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, google-sheets-formula, divide-by-zero

So I would like to create a function or something that returns absolutely nothing in a cell.
When I say nothing, I mean that if the cell before returns an array of value, it can write in this cell and doesn't returns `#REF` (Cannot expand results).

The idea is that I have a function `sort()` that get me a list of `keys`. Then I retrieve the `values` with a filter function like so :

```js
=FILTER(B$2:B$7, A$2:A$7=D2)
```

But sometimes the keys (which are dates) can be duplicated, and that makes that the `FILTER` function with return 2 times 2 rows, creating a `#REF` error (cannot expand results).

If I create a condition :

```js
=IF(D1<>D2, FILTER(/*...*/), "")
```

The second cell is empty but I still get the `#REF` error, because it's not really empty.

Is there a way to make that work ?

Comment: No. There's nothing like that. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/ `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` is the only way here.

Comment: Can you share an example sheet with data, your actual result and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to create a function or something that returns absolutely nothing in a cell

try:

```
=IFERROR(0/0)
```

or:

```
=IF(;;)
```

but what you actually need is:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B$7, A$2:A$7=D2))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B$2:B$7, A$2:A$7=D2), 1)
```

or:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(B$2:B$7, A$2:A$7=D2), 1, 1)
```

Comment: I could fix the issue by combining different functions that you provided. So I used the `FILTER` function to get all the corresponding lines, and the `INDEX` function together with a `COUNTIF()` in order to return the correct line.