# How to display value if value is unique or duplicate in a column using an arrayformula Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula that returns either `Unique` or `Duplicate` depending on whether there already exists another value in the same column.

The formula `=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)=1, "Unique", "Duplicate")` in `B2`

Example:

```
  A      B
Peter | Unique
James | Unique
Peter | Duplicate
Anne  | Unique
James | Duplicate
```

The formula works as it should but I am looking for an alternative formula that works with `arrayformula()`

The reason is because my data is dynamic which means the ranges change time and time again. It's not possible to manually drag the current formula each time the ranges change so an arrayformula for this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to be able to specify the range in this case `A2:A` once in [`LAMBDA()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) call.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 LAMBDA(r   ,IF(r="",,IF(XMATCH(r,r,0,1)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(r))<>TRUE,
       "Duplicate","Unique")))
       (A2:A))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) - [**`ROWS`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382) - [**`UNIQUE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)

Answer (score 2):

Lets try `BYROW()`. BYROW is by default dynamic spill array formula.

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,x)>1,"Duplicate","Unique")))
```

- Here `A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A2** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply ***COUNTIFS()*** function for each cell of ***A column*** and will display result based on TRUE/FALSE argument.

[image]

Comment: Wasn't able to make the second formula work. It's returning all Unique even when they are not. My filter column is alphanumeric. Could that have affected?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, INDEX(IF(COUNTIFS(x, x, ROW(x), "<="&ROW(x))>1, 
 "duplicate", "unique")))(A1:A5)
```

[image]