# Using Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA to Concatenate Series of Item Based from Lowest to Highest Values per Row

Tags: google-sheets, sequence, array-formulas, string-concatenation

I have a table with three Columns:
Column A: name of Item,
Column B: Lowest value of series,
Column C: the Highest value of series.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqlMY.png)

What I want to achieve is:

1. Generate series of item sequence from lowest number to highest number per row

So Apple 7 9  will yield: "Apple_7", "Apple_8", "Apple_9"

2. Concatenate/Join such sequence per row into Column D
   So

   | Item | From | Until | Result |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | Apple | 7 | 9 | "Apple_7, Apple_8, Apple_9" |
   | Berry | 3 | 8 | "Berry_3, Berry_4, Berry_5, Berry_6, Berry_7, Berry_8" |
3. Doing it all using one Arrayformula, so that new row added can be automatically calculated.

Here is example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R5raKmmt5-aOIorAZGHjv_-fdySKWjCMB_FRQwm1vag/edit#gid=0

I tried in Column D:

```
arrayformula(textjoin(", ",true,arrayformula(A3:A&"_"&sequence(1,C3:C-B3:B+1,B3:B,1))))
```

Apparently, the sequence function only take value from Column B and join it in first row.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below `BYROW()` formula (see your file, harun24hr sheet).

```
=BYROW(A3:INDEX(A3:A,COUNTA(A3:A)),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(";",1,INDEX(x&"_"& SEQUENCE(INDEX(C:C,ROW(x))-INDEX(B:B,ROW(x))+1,1,INDEX(B:B,ROW(x)))))))
```

- Here `A3:INDEX(A3:A,COUNTA(A3:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A3** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply ***TEXTJOIN()*** and ***SEQUENCE()*** function for each cell of ***B as well as C column***.
- `SEQUENCE()` will make series from start to end number and by concatenating A column and will generate your desired strings.
- Finally `TEXTJOIN()` will join all those strings with delimiter to a single cell.

[image]

Comment: Wow, Amazing.. Just the one I need!
Thank you so much. :-D

Comment: @RayDaapala If the answer helps then please consider to accept it. See this article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try REDUCE:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(REDUCE(, A3:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))), 
 LAMBDA(x, a, {x; JOIN(, LAMBDA(i, f, u, i&"_"&SEQUENCE(1, u-f+1, f)&";")
 (a, OFFSET(a,,1), OFFSET(a,,2)))})), "offset 1", ))
```

[image]