# Find names in string and combinations & lookup for value - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've a data set with list of names & combinations and need to map with the team.

For ex, if the list of name is unique, then it should give me team name.. If the name of combination from team, it should give same team name.. Combination between two teams, then it should say team C.

Here is the trix for ref: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1leb0hQ5gb6RclcMb__JYJLqvIFBQD_B3v7c2o4PbICg/edit#gid=0

I tried lookup, but it is fulling first case but not the people combination. Is there any way I can achieve this. Also, I assume these names are separated by ascii CHAR(10).

Let me know any inputs or suggestions so I can fulfil this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use below formula-

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,UNIQUE(INDEX(XLOOKUP(FLATTEN(SPLIT(x,CHAR(10))),E2:E7,F2:F7,,0))))),"C")
```

- Here `A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A2** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply ***XLOOKUP()*** function for each cell of ***A column***.
- `SPLIT()` will separate all values from cell using line break `CHAR(10)` delimiter.
- `XLOOKUP()` will search for name and return team.
- For multiple names, `UNIQUE()` function will return only unique teams.
- Finaly `BYROW()` will return that unique team. If there are more than 1 teams, then `BYROW()` will through error.
- `IFERROR()` will catch that error and return `C` as result/exception.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this formula. It's a little long but splits the value of each cell, joins them to see if they're unique or not, and then applies C if they aren't:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,lambda(val,IF(val="","",lambda(results,SI(COUNTA(results)=1,results,"C"))(UNIQUE(transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP (SPLIT(val,CHAR(10)),E$2:F,2,0))))))))
```

Comment: It expands through all the column