# What aggregation function to concatenate string like sum() for number in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Basically I would like to convert the following table

| Name | Team |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | X |
| A | Y |
| B | Z |
| C | X |
| A | Z |

to

| Name | Team |
| --- | --- |
| A | X,Y,Z |
| B | X,Z |
| C | X |

It is something like `sum(B) group by A` but for strings rather than numbers

What kind of Google Sheet formula or Query() can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(
 REGEXREPLACE(
  SPLIT(
   TRANSPOSE(
    QUERY(
     QUERY(
      SPLIT(
       FILTER(A2:A&"♦♥"&B2:B,A2:A<>"")&",",
      "♥"
      ),
      "SELECT MAX(Col2) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1",0
     ),,10^7
    )
   ),
   "♦"
  ),
  "^(?:,?\s*)+|(?:,\s*)$|(,)\s*(?:,\s*)*","$1"
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula-

```
={UNIQUE(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))),BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))),LAMBDA(x,JOIN(",",FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=x))))}
```

- Here `A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A2** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply for each unique value return by `INDEX()` function to gather corresponded values from ***B column***.
- Inside lambda, `JOIN()` will concat those filtered values into one single string.
- And finally, by `{}` results will be combined into on array for output.

[image]