# How do i fix the value of sumifs in Google sheets when i add more rows in the bottom?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

[image]

I would need the amount available for each code based on the country and maximum available limit is 12400.
But when i try to execute it the values in D3, D6 and D7 are changing as we keep on adding the rows but this is how i basically need it
D3 should be 11,166 (12400-1234)
D6 should be 4623 (11,166-6543)
D7 should be -60,809 (4623-65432)

Can you please help me with a formula which would make my life easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula out in cell D3 of your sample data

`=MAP(A3:A,B3:B,LAMBDA(ax,bx,IF(ax="",,12400-SUM(FILTER(C3:C,A3:A=ax,B3:B=bx,ROW(A3:A)<=ROW(ax))))))`

-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! this is of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `BYROW()` to iterate each row of ***Code*** column. Try-

```
=BYROW(A3:INDEX(A3:A,COUNTA(A3:A)),LAMBDA(x,12400-SUMIFS(C3:C,A3:A,x,B3:B,"India")))
```

- Here `A3:INDEX(A3:A,COUNTA(A3:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A3** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply to ***SUMIFS()*** function for each cell of ***A column***.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! this is of great help :)

Comment: @NeethuSinguluri If you find the answer helpful, then please accept the answer (tick mark it) so that other visitor can know this is solved.