# Fetch names through duplicate User ID and show all names in Unique IDs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets in Google Sheets.
In spreadsheet 1 - Column A has the User ID (including duplicate ID) and Column B has Names.
In Sheet 2 - Column A has a Unique ID.

I want names to be shown in Column B in spreadsheet 2 (if in 1 User ID there are multiple names and it should show all the names in the unique ID.

I tried the below formula but it is showing the wrong names (names are not matching with the corresponding User ID).

In another sheet I got Unique IDs through: =UNIQUE(Sheet2!A:A) and names through =JOIN(",",FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A = Sheet2!A1))

Attaching screenshots for reference.
Spreadsheet 1
[image]

Spreadsheet 2
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below lambda formula-

```
=LAMBDA(lm,{lm,MAP(lm,LAMBDA(x,JOIN(", ",FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=x))))})(UNIQUE(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Harun24hr. It worked like a charm.  Can this formula work only to show names as well ?

Comment: Could you please share from where can I learn more about this function?

Comment: Go through this one by @The Master. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747

Comment: To show names only use `=MAP(UNIQUE(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))),LAMBDA(x,JOIN(", ",FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=x))))`.