# Improve performance of Google Sheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I've a google sheet formula which I am using to repeat values n number of times, formula is this:-

> =ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(values,num_repeat,XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(num_repeat)),VSTACK(1,SCAN(1,num_repeat,LAMBDA(init,repeat,init+repeat))),VSTACK(values,""),,-1))(A1:A,B1:B))

Here `A1:A` contains Text values which I want to repeat number of times in range `B1:B`, formula works absolutely fine, but it is very slow, I have large dataset on which I am applying this formula, can anyone help me to improve the formula getting the same result. I think sequence is causing issue, although I am not sure, or there any other alternative without making the formula too big.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below formula-

```
=REDUCE("Repeat Texts",B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B)),
LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,MAKEARRAY(x,1,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(A:A,ROW(x)))))))
```

`LAMBDA()` formula would be-

```
=LAMBDA(Input1,Input2,REDUCE("Repeat Texts",Input2,
LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,MAKEARRAY(x,1,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(Input1,ROW(x))))))))(A:A,B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B)))
```

Another easy solution can be-

```
=TOCOL((INDEX(SPLIT(REPT(TOCOL(A2:A,1)&"|",TOCOL(B2:B,1)),"|"))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harun it worked, can you point out what was causing my formula was working slow, please if you can?

Comment: @vector Can you please try this one `=TOCOL((INDEX(SPLIT(REPT(TOCOL(A2:A,1)&"|",TOCOL(B2:B,1)),"|"))),1)`.

Comment: @vector You formula was calculating whole column and inner loop (nested iterative function like SCAN) made the formula slow. ArrayFormula calculate for full column.

Comment: `=TOCOL((INDEX(SPLIT(REPT(TOCOL(A2:A,1)&"|",TOCOL(B2:B,1)),"|"))),1)` this didn;t worked as expected, it is creating another column in my dataset

Comment: can you please explain why you used `B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B))`

Comment: @vector Here `B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **B2** to last non empty cell in column B (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster

Comment: I only have blank rows at the bottom of dataset

Comment: Hope above explanation make it clear to understand.

Comment: I am having issue with this formula, it is not repeating values like ideally it should be , on my dataset it is repeating other value more and removing count of other, you'll understand this more on this sample sheet :- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYZf0CAKr1NvgGBV8rJwTt3rwdBhKeYrwp1UGMGL6GA/edit#gid=0

Comment: While your data starts from `B1` then the lambda input will be `B1:INDEX(B1:B,COUNTA(B1:B))`.

Answer (score 1):

[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYZf0CAKr1NvgGBV8rJwTt3rwdBhKeYrwp1UGMGL6GA/edit#gid=2112401635):

=tocol(map(A:A,B:B,lambda(a,b,if(a="",,wraprows(a,b,a)))),3)

[image]