# How to auto-detect the number of items from FILTER and apply FORMULA

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Filter Formula that will fit based on conditions and produce a list of items based on::

```
FILTER('Sheet1'!B42:B,'Sheet1'!L42:L="Yes")
B
```

I will use some FORMULA (such as VLOOK, UP, and SUM...) to calculate based on the keyword from the generate list from there:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Filter List Item 1 | VLOOKUP ('Filter List Item 1') |
| Filter List Item 2 | VLOOKUP ('Filter List Item 2') |
| Filter List Item 3 | VLOOKUP ('Filter List Item 3') |

The fact that the list of Filter items changes frequently raises my concern
My question is, How can I determine how many items the FILTER generated in column A every times and consistently apply the corresponding formula to column B?

I anticipated, for example, that if 20 filter items appeared, 20 corresponding formulas would be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAP()`, `BYROW()` will work in this situation. `ARRAYFORMULA()` will also work. I will go with `MAP()` function.

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,"VLOOKUP ('" & x & "')"))
```

Adjust `VLOOKUP()` to your actual case.

- Here `A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A2** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply ***VLOOKUP()*** function for each cell of ***A column***.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it was as I anticipated. In range C:F I need to summarize some of the numbers in each column, how can I do it? Tried: =MAP(I161:INDEX(I161:I,COUNTA(I161:I)),LAMBDA(x,SUM(C:F))) but not success

Comment: In this case you have to use `BYROW()` function like `=BYROW(C161:F,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand this, you only need to create IF statement if the cell is not empty..

> IF(A2<>"",VLOOKUP(A2),"")

or use arrayFormula to autofill the rest of the column if row count is undefined:

> =ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A<>"",VLOOKUP(A2:A,RANGE,INDEX),""))