# Excel filters multiple column unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have some large not fixed length of data in Excel in multiple columns.
I want to list 2 columns (timestamps) in another worksheet with =UNIQUE(Sheet1!M:N;FALSE;FALSE), but filters out empty cells.
Empty cells can cause UNIQUE function to add an additional row, and if formatted it to date it will contains 1900/01/01.

If I set the ranges to M1:N345 it is good, but the data is variable length in every sheet.

ChatGPT really unusable for this task...

How can I skip the empty rows, or iterate only where it is data at this columns?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Added sample excel code

[image]

Comment: Could you explain it with some samples?

Comment: Apply a Filter to the data before applying Unique: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B, A:A<>""), FALSE, FALSE))`

Comment: Might need to be `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B,(A:A<>"")*(B:B<>"")),FALSE,FALSE)` or `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B,(A:A<>"")+(B:B<>"")),FALSE,FALSE)` depending on how to handle rows with 1 value and 1 blank.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try the following formula-

```
=UNIQUE(A1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)))
```

- Here `A1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A1** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then use `UNIQUE()` function to get distinct values.

[image]