# Google Sheets Array Formula with Multiple Sequences of Varying Lengths, Starting Numbers, and Suffixes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've got a unique situation where I'm trying to determine the numbers present in multiple, variable, sequences. Assume each column and row start at A1.

| StartNum | NumItems | Suffix | Sequence Formula | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | e | 1e | 2e |  |  |  |
| 20 | 5 | d | 20d | 21d | 22d | 23d | 24d |
| 33 | 4 | a | 33a | 34a | 35a | 36a |  |

I can achieve the results in Columns D and beyond with the following formulas into D1, D2, and D3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(1,B1,A1,1)&C1)
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(1,B2,A2,1)&C2)
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(1,B3,A3,1)&C3)
```

As I add additional rows, however, I have to manually copy down the formula in D1/D2. I'd love to have a single formula in D1 that generates the entire 2D array of values, with the ultimate goal of eventually concatenating everything into a single string that is pipe-separated using something like JOIN("|",{some-array-formula}) to achieve the final result of "1e|2e|20d|21d|22d|23d|24d|33a|34a|35a|36a".

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? I've tried the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(1,B1:B,A1:A,1)&C1:C))
```

but that didn't accomplish what I was looking for in terms of building the multi-dimensional array. Instead it just gives me a single-column array with just the values in Column D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below formula-

```
=LET(lr,COUNTA(A2:A),
a,A2:INDEX(A2:A,lr),
b,B2:INDEX(B2:B,lr),
c,C2:INDEX(C2:C,lr),
INDEX(MAP(a,b,c,LAMBDA(x,y,z,SEQUENCE(1,y,x)&z))))
```

- Here `A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))` will return a array of values as well cell reference from **A2** to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). Same for ***Col_B*** and ***Col_C***. If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/5514747) by @TheMaster
- Then `LAMBDA()` will apply ***SEQUENCE()*** function for each cell of ***A, B, C column***.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This did exactly what I needed it to and gave me the information I needed to finish what I was looking to do! Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: @AndrewGoulart Glad to know it helps!