ArrayFormula is breaking the CopyPaste() funtion. Create new row but empty
I have the copyPaste function active on a google sheet that copies the new rows created on the sheet to another sheet. Everything works regularly.
function copyPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx);
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("yyyyy");
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("zzzzzz");
  var target = sss.getSheetByName("jjjjjj")
  var targetRow = target.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  var values = source.getRange(source.getLastRow(), 1, 1, source.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //getting the values form `New_Customers` sheet
  var bval = values[0][1];
  var cval = values[0][2];
  var eval = values[0][4];
  var gval = values[0][6];
  var dval = values[0][3];

  //setting the values to `Sheet1` sheet
  target.getRange(targetRow, 1).setValue(bval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 2).setValue(cval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 3).setValue(eval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 5).setValue(gval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 11).setValue(dval);
}

Today I added 2 columns with some ARRAYFORMULA functions to the main sheet
Now the CopyPaste function doesn't work anymore.
Example:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=""; ""; TEXT(TODAY(); "MM/DD")-TEXT(A2:A; "MM/DD")))

In the destination sheet a new row is created but it remains empty, no data is copied from the main sheet.
Is there some conflict between the two things?
If I delete the two columns created with ARRAYFORMULA inside everything works regularly again.
Help.
Thank you very much

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883862/arrayformula-is-breaking-the-getlastrow-funtion-possible-workarounds
